# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$store') when deploying

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vuex, store

I am creating a Vue app and using Vuex store. I am using the store in my navbar. When I run locally using `npm run serve`, the navbar shows and everything works fine. However, when I deploy it using Vercel, it gives me an error - "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$store')".

This is my landing page

```
<template>
  <div class="LandingView">
    <Nav />
    <Header/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
// import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";
import Header from "@/components/Header.vue";
import Nav from "@/components/Nav.vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "LandingView",
  components: {
    // HelloWorld,
    Nav,
    Header,
  },
  mounted () {
    const store = useStore();
    store.dispatch('getPendingEvents').then(result => {
      console.log('getPendingEvents', result);
    })
  },
};
</script>
```

This is my navbar component

```
<script setup>
/* eslint-disable */

import { auth } from '@/firebase/firebaseInit';
import {RouterLink, RouterView} from 'vue-router';
</script>

<template>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #f7dfc2"
>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" id="navBarLogo" href="#"></a> -->
          <router-link class="nav-link" :to="{name: 'Landing'}"><img src="@/assets/navschedoo.png" height="40"></router-link>



        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" 
        data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" 
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 100px;">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <span  class="navbar-text" >
        <div v-if="(this.$store.state.user)" class="profile pButton" ref="profile" @click="toggle" style="position: absolute; top: 7px; right: 30px;">
        {{this.$store.state.profileInitials}}
        <div class="profile-menu" id="profileMenu" hidden>
              <div class="info">
                  <p class="initials">{{this.$store.state.profileInitials}}</p>
                  <div class="right">
                      <p>{{this.$store.state.profileFirstName}} {{this.$store.state.profileLastName}}</p>
                      <p>{{this.$store.state.profileUsername}} </p>
                      <p>{{this.$store.state.profileEmail}} </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="options">
                  <div class="option">
                      <router-link class-="option" :to="{name: 'Settings'}"
                      style="color: black; text-decoration: none;"
                      >
                          <userIcon class="icon"/>
                          <p
                          style="padding-top: 10px"
                          >Profile</p>
                      </router-link>
                  </div>
                  <div @click="signOut" class="option">
                      <router-link class="option" to="#"
                      style="color: black; text-decoration: none"
                      >
                          <!-- <userIcon class="icon"/> -->
                          <p
                          >Sign Out</p>
                      </router-link>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

      </div>
      </span>


        <div v-if="(this.$store.state.user)" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="height: 40px">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
              <!-- <a class="nav-link active">My Calendar</a> -->
              <router-link class="nav-link" :to="{name: 'Calendar'}"
              style="color: black; text-decoration: none;"
              >My Calendar</router-link>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Insights</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Focus</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- <span class="navbar-text" style="right: 5%">
              <router-link @click='signOut' class="nav-link" to="#"
              style="color: black; text-decoration: none;"
              >Sign Out</router-link>
          </span> -->
        </div>



        <div v-if="(!this.$store.state.user)" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent"
        style="height: 40px">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" @click="toAbout">About Us</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <span  class="navbar-text" style="right: 5%">
              <router-link class="nav-link" :to="{name: 'Login'}"
              style="color: black; text-decoration: none;"
              >Login</router-link>
          </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "header",
  data() {
    return {
      hidden: true,
      loggedin: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.hidden = !this.hidden;
      document.getElementById("profileMenu").hidden = this.hidden;
    },

    signOut() {
      auth.signOut();
      // window.location.reload();
      window.location.href = "/login";
    },


    toAbout() {
      console.log("Button clicked"); // Check if this message is logged
      const about = document.getElementById("about-us");
      about.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    },
  }, 
  computed: {
    user() {
      return this.$store.state.user;
    }
  }

};

</script>
```

this is my router, index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import LandingView from '../views/LandingView.vue';
import Login from '../views/Login.vue';
import Register from '../views/Register.vue';
import ForgetPassword from '../views/ForgetPassword.vue';
import Settings from '../views/SettingsView.vue';
// import CreateEvent from '/src/components/CreateEvent.vue';
import CalendarView from '../views/CalendarView.vue';
import CrEvent from '../components/CrEvent.vue';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';
// import Calendar from '../components/Calendar.vue';
import store from '@/store/index.js';

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "about",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/AboutView.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/landing",
    name: "Landing",
    component: LandingView,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    component: Login,
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    name: "Register",
    component: Register,
  },
  {
    path: "/forget-password",
    name: "ForgetPassword",
    component: ForgetPassword,
  },
  {
    path: "/calendar",
    name: "Calendar",
    component: CalendarView,
    beforeEnter: (to, from , next) => {
      if (store.state.profileId){
        next();
      } else {
        next('/login')
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/create-event",
    name: "CrEvent",
    component: CrEvent,
  },
  {
    path: "/settings",
    name: "Settings",
    component: Settings,
  }, 
  {
    path: "/home",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  }
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Hi, [Pinia is now a better choice than Vuex](https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html#Comparison-with-Vuex)

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce. There's nothing that could explain the difference in prod. $store is exposed by vuex plugin. That it's not there means that app init wasn't correctly executed.

Comment: @KaiKai Probably true, but why is this relevant? vuex is already being used in the project and it doesn't have innate problems in a case like this one